# CMake target doesn't install to component

Tags: cmake

I have this install code:

```
add_library(foo SHARED ...)
install(TARGETS foo
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin  # foo.dll
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib  # libfoo.so
  COMPONENT libs)
install(FILES conf DESTINATION etc COMPONENT libs)
```

On linux things work great.  After `cpack`, the `-libs` package contains everything.

On windows, things don't work great.  After `cpack` I get a `-libs` package containing `etc/conf`, but no `bin/foo.dll`.

If I `make install` (no component installation), then `install_manifest.txt` contains everything.

Why isn't `foo.dll` deployed in the windows component install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
install(TARGETS foo
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin  # foo.dll
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib  # libfoo.so
  COMPONENT libs)
```

There is no `RUNTIME DESTINATION` argument.  Instead there is a `RUNTIME` argument, and several commands which affect `RUNTIME` including `DESTINATION` and `COMPONENT`.  With correct indenting, what you wrote is:

```
install(TARGETS foo
  RUNTIME
    DESTINATION bin
  LIBRARY
    DESTINATION lib
    COMPONENT libs
)
```

Now you can see that `COMPONENT` only applies to `LIBRARY` and not `RUNTIME`.  The solution is:

```
install(TARGETS foo
  RUNTIME
    DESTINATION bin # foo.dll
    COMPONENT libs
  LIBRARY
    DESTINATION lib # libfoo.so
    COMPONENT libs
)
```